# Could not find fastlane in current directory

Tags: continuous-integration, testflight, circleci, fastlane

I've having fastlane folder is able to run fastlane match development and fastlane match appstore but receiving this error while running bundle exec fastlane $FASTLANE ios beta on circleci. What else do I need to configure in order to make this work?

Here's the output it's producing:-

```
[12:32:24]: All required keys, certificates and provisioning profiles are installed 
[⠋]  [⠙]  [⠹]  [⠸]  [⠼]  [⠴]  [⠦]  [✔] 
[12:32:27]: Could not find fastlane in current directory. Make sure to have your fastlane configuration files inside a folder called "fastlane". Would you like to set fastlane up?

Looking for related GitHub issues on fastlane/fastlane...

➡️ Fastlain Android screengrab. Could not retrieve response as fastlane runs in non-interactive mode
#14869 [open] 4 
2 weeks ago

➡️ FastLane 2.124 FastlaneCore::Interface::FastlaneCrash: [!] Could not retrieve response as fastlane runs in non-interactive mode
#14835 [open] 4 
2 weeks ago

➡️ Supply isn't working on CI with Google auth .p12 files
#14128 [closed] 2 
20 Apr 2019

and 36 more at: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/search?q=Could%20not%20retrieve%20response%20as%20fastlane%20runs%20in%20non-interactive%20mode&type=Issues&utf8=✓

 You can ⌘ + double-click on links to open them directly in your browser.
bundler: failed to load command: fastlane (/usr/local/bin/fastlane)
FastlaneCore::Interface::FastlaneCrash: [!] Could not retrieve response as fastlane runs in non-interactive mode
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.126.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/interface.rb:129:in crash!' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.126.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/implementations/shell.rb:155:in verify_interactive!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.126.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/implementations/shell.rb:133:in confirm' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.126.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/ui.rb:17:in method_missing'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.126.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:343:in ensure_fastfile' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.126.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:107:in block (2 levels) in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:178:in call' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/command.rb:153:in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:476:in run_active_command' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.126.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:76:in run!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/delegates.rb:15:in run!' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.126.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:333:in run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.126.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:41:in start' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.126.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:119:in take_off'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/fastlane-2.126.0/bin/fastlane:23:in <top (required)>' /usr/local/bin/fastlane:22:in load'
/usr/local/bin/fastlane:22:in `<top (required)>'
Exited with code 1
```

Comment: What is `bundle exec fastlane $FASTLANE ios beta` - why the `$FASTLANE` in the command? Can you edit your question to contain the _full_ output you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add additional step to check if fastlane is installed properly

`bundle check || bundle install --path vendor/bundle`

If you are using CircleCI 2.0 following step would be needed

```
jobs:
  ...
  setupFastLane:
    executor:
      name: default
    steps:
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Select Ruby Version
          command:  echo "ruby-2.4" > .ruby-version
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - m2-gems-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
          - m2-gems-
      - run:
          name: Install Ruby Gems
          command: bundle check || bundle install --path vendor/bundle
          environment:
            BUNDLE_JOBS: 4
            BUNDLE_RETRY: 3
      - save_cache:
          key: m2-gems-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
          paths:
            - vendor/bundle
```

Answer (score 0):

**Flutter and Github Actions for Android:**

If you are setting up `Github Actions` for a `Flutter` project for `android` and run into this error in one of your steps, see the work flow below:

```
jobs:
  release:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      LC_ALL: en_US.UTF-8
      LANG: en_US.UTF-8
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1

      - name: Setup Fastlane
        working-directory: ./android  # <-- Make sure you have this
        run: bundle install

      - name: Run Fastlane
        working-directory: ./android. # <-- Make sure you have this
        run: bundle exec fastlane android [lane name]
```

Make sure to setup the `ruby/setup-ruby@v1` action correctly depending on your project. see the doc: https://github.com/ruby/setup-ruby

In my case I have not specified the ruby version because I am using the `.ruby-version` file in my project.